# Partial<Observer<unknown>> error when trying to type next value in subscribe

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've created a rxjs stream with a couple of operators in it, which I will show you in a bit, but first I would like to describe the error

I have the following (simplified)

```
return fromEvent(....).pipe(
  ....
).subscribe((output: IOutput<IData>) => ....); // <-- error
```

[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cy7nfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Futils.ts)

Unfortunately the stackblitz demo doesn't give any errors, it happens in my IDE only. The error I get is

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<unknown>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(output: IOutput<IData>) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<unknown>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: unknown) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(output: IOutput<IData>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'output' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IOutput<IData>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: unknown) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(output: IOutput<IData>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'output' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'IOutput<IData>'.ts(2769)
```

[image]

The weird thing is that I can let the error go away if I comment out one of the operators

[image]

Here I commented out the `tap` operator, but the same thing happens when I comment out that `filter` operator.

Another way to fix this, is to rewrite the `subscribe` into

```
 .subscribe((output)  => observer.next(output as IOutput<IData>));
```

But whatever I do, I no clue what is going on here. For example, how can commenting out that `tap` operator solve the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't show up on StackBlitz due to the tsconfig settings (probably `strictFunctionTypes`), but you can reproduce it in a TypeScript playground.

The issue is that the `rxjs` type definitions only type `pipe` overloads for up to 10 arguments. Beyond 10, the result type becomes `Observable<unknown>`.

You can fix it by chaining pipes together once you reach ten operators:

```
const sub = fromEvent<Event>(document, 'click', { capture: true })
  .pipe(
    xPreventPropagation$<Event>(),
    ..
    tap((update) => console.log('test3')))
  .pipe(
    map<IData, IOutput<IData>>((update: IData) => ({
      result: update,
    }))
  )
  .subscribe((output: IOutput<IData>) => observer.next(output));
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwLACg5wPICMDOBTKANwEMsAbPAGlXQDMoIQBRQvAOxmrThGLC-QATYDhjA2AYxgBVDsDIBhABbE2AczyCBcUcVgB1YDCXaYfbTgDuRiUoCy5mnFryYBbXYhsIAFQCeYHgYgVDEMNAAYgCukmJe2hC0XAC%20zgwgcADkUAAeAFY4mQDcqKh4OZCwcOJuULTEEnhwAJIAImHEiE74FFLQAFw6MFDiaiXcbjkwg6Ij6uPoIs1sYFHTcFgQEBSq48mlKOWV8DUE9Y0tGGurMAA8PgB8XdxQeDhRZOs%20ewdH0PC0GJSYBeHR4GBRMAACgAlM90K8IVA2HA2HhLJhcAQSOQ8LdmlcYDd8e0zA8HlCoRAsUQCHCALxPZDcdASLyiHRRLBwelpRgsdh3AUcCmCCASKIgQWULISMjACQAa0yMoQcAkfCReEGwyiTWSMKc6HQADowMBAlCjcb0DkAAqvVgcB0QMDENRhEFsAAkt2FMApMO0NvQvDAfqdnBapOIFKheEjg39DKZ1pDcERUWR8PTIZ6eD6UEGmWEhBNWD0tC2KrTucm60yFagNZZucWOGWN0G9TI%20GDudSxBw0Y6CwHQdrQhEYlisjEihU6k0JI6FMnxqhYEdMolUCgKbgW4TJvzhZ59N5u6gJ7wvXCUHXE9bNt0BiMShXZKhzLb6FP9%20LFtfzgeti2IIDfyWFY1m7YheyodcDX7G0zGhWEeVTZ8QzZNgcG2PATTICA1ChTI3FETIYTHdMkPXKwbHsPhP2IGVsHwIhSAoZjyUpSFBDCPAU3XW19GIIwImgJgKClDgoT4gSbzvaAYTNC08ChMNKQPeS3BhQ0sPQJ82xyAAJYA1CUeULJgX02lXWFkONFxPgIXiwH43SMLgABCbydII-9lMc9BULcjzBK8nC8IoQjiNI8iYAAZkovTa1Uy11zDZiZQJa41m4uN-MGOyzAPb9hIzN4PnWfzgrgA19PTRqQxPLkcAkEYsHUqk8vWXKiXykrYwPal2NYa80SmHqBpgPTxmtTNs3QxkcxfLkTRid5cA64Authaj6rHA0fhQVBAViL04HtR1BRdN0PTiH17jgco3DYQRh39QNBk8bx-ECYICDCSIgUe%205MIRcEsxRUL40TOAfAPH9jQTQUzRujhWjwepqv261UY4E9wjAO73U9Lw8dbAmYCJ11mhAKVhAE0mHq9Sn0GO1B9lOw4Kn%20ZxQcunJRPEyTpMFKFAqLIY5jUGFBjY7FOLxTZ8NUCHqloOAoW8qW4AAH31sElKgc9eUySjVsqpEUUSKFdUEo6Dkhm3UXRTExuV25VZ2Ng41G7E6S85G-3BHxQDwCA1i04Payi%20BXneT4eTgMUJRkmmAEc9SgPwAGVbwLe9JcLwsqOdkMA9pCbXp17zE%20q8usKr8aTTZcAKDcdnjWSGUAEYAAYh6bjmm%205so%20aqc7gVBUzzMs%20ebNuJwfBeqZ2A%20xBjaLgYZdGerUG%20uBft8AIghCYGoGiC6vHBnNFphvgwoEwZEci9l8NikiyLeGA%205Sk6QA)

Comment: That makes sense. I did look at the `pipe` interface ( pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>( ...) which makes sense now. Thanks a lot!!